# How to arrange data week wise csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have generated csv file which has formate as shown in below image:
In this image, I have data week wise but somewhere I couldn't arrange data week wise. If you look into the below image, you will see the red mark and blue mark. I want to separate this both marks. How I will do it? 
**Note:** If Holiday on Friday then it should set a week from Monday to Thursday.

currently, I'm using below logic :

**Image:** [Please click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIqm0.png)

**current logic:**

```
import csv
blank_fields=[' ']
fields=[' ','Weekly Avg']

# Read csv file
file1 = open('test.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(file1)
new_rows_list = []

# Read data row by row  and store into new list
for row in reader:
    new_rows_list.append(row)
    if 'Friday' in row:
        new_rows_list.append(fields)
file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another logic for this same thing and it is successfully worked and easy solution.

```
import csv
import datetime

fields={'':' ', 'Date':'Weekly Avg'}

#Read csv file
file1 = open('temp.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.DictReader(file1)
new_rows_list = []

last_date = None

# Read data row by row  and store into new list
for row in reader:
   cur_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
   if last_date and ((last_date.weekday() > cur_date.weekday()) or (cur_date.weekday() == 0)):
       new_rows_list.append(fields)
   last_date = cur_date
   new_rows_list.append(row)
file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

overall you are going towards the right direction, your condition is just a little too error prone, things can get worse (e.g., just one day in a week appears in your list). So testing for the weekday string isn't the best choice here.

I would suggest "understanding" the date/time in your table to solve this using weekdays, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td

# remember the last weekday
last = None
# each item in list represents one week, while active_week is a temp-var
weeks = []
_cur_week = []
for row in reader:
    # assuming the date is in row[1] (split, convert to int, pass as args)
    _cur_date = dt(*map(int, row[1].split("-")))

    # weekday will be in [0 .. 6]
    # now if _cur_date.weekday <= last.weekday, a week is complete
    # (also catching corner-case with more than 7 days, between two entries)
    if last and (_cur_date.weekday <= last.weekday or (_cur_date - last) >= td(days=7)):

        # append collected rows to 'weeks', empty _cur_week for next rows
        weeks.append(_cur_week)
        _cur_week = []

    # regular invariant, append row and set 'last' to '_cur_date'
    _cur_week.append(row)
    last = _cur_date
```

Pretty verbose and extensive, but I hope I can transport the pattern used here:

- parse existing date and use weekday to distinguish one week from another (i.e., weekday will increase monotonously, means any decrease (or equality) will tell you the current date represents the next week).
- store `rows` in a temporary list during one week
- append `_cur_week` into `weeks` once the condition for next week gets triggered
- empty `_cur_week` for next rows i.e., week

Finally the last thing to do is to "concat" the data e.g. like this:

```
new_rows_list = [[fields] + week for week in weeks]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion But I have another logic for this same thing and it is successfully worked and easy solution.